# Function.bind vs Closure in Javascript : how to choose?

Tags: javascript

As said here:

[http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20110601055159/http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html)

> Closures can also be used to resolve issues with the this keyword,
> which is unique to each scope. This
> mechanism can be particularly useful
> when dealing with callbacks, though in
> those cases, it is often better to use
> Function.bind, which will avoid any
> overhead associated with scope
> traversal.

But it doesn't really say how to distinguish between the two cases. I don't understand in fact what the author means by "avoid any overhead associated with scope traversal." Can you explain?

Comment: closure method seems to be twice faster http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-closure-performace

Comment: Link is broken. "Sorry, what you’re looking for isn’t here"

Comment: @sbr 25 x faster on my computer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at this line in the example in the link above

```
console.log(self.myName, this.myName);
```

(with self = this; a couple of lines above). The closure defined outerFunction method, exists in a different scope that is why it has a different this value from the outerObj object. (self.myName!=this.myName)

Scope traversal means, when you are reaching to grab a value (variable,object) that exists in a different scope, therefore additional overhead is added (code becomes slower to execute).

Using bind, you 're calling a function with an existing scope, so that scope traversal does not take place.

Comment: *code becomes slower to execute* - this is completely wrong as indicated by sbr's comment and other SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638305/why-is-bind-slower-than-a-closure

Comment: Can you provide more context surrounding the line of code you added? The link provided in the original question is no longer valid.

Comment: Also, can you provide any documentation or evidence to explain "when you are reaching to grab a value that exists in a different scope, additional overhead is added". The performance check linked above by @sbr seems to show that closure is the same - even a bit faster.

Comment: Not so: self is generally faster than bind in 2015: https://jsperf.com/bind-vs-closure-setup/6

Answer (score 11):

What it's referring to are things like this

```
obj.doSomething = function() {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    // this is the window
    // that is the obj
    that.doSomethingElse();
  }, 50);
};
```

vs

```
obj.doSomething = function() {
  setTimeout((function() {
    // this is the obj
    this.doSomethingElse();
  }).bind(this), 50);
};
```

[Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-closure-23). No noticable difference in chrome.

Comment: Since function calls happen in microseconds and setTimeout is 10milliseconds+, isn't this lack of difference caused by setTimeout's low timing resolution?

Comment: Yes, but which of the two is considered best practice (ie. the "nicest to read")?

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck that is considered personal preference. I completely avoid using `this` in JavaScript since both variants are ugly.

Comment: Using the `this` keyword is fundamental to object oriented programming. I would recommend against the suggestion given by @Raynos.

Comment: I find the first example nicest to read (...as long as a different variable name is used besides "that". *that*'s confusing IMO.)

Comment: @Raynos, If I would like not not use this in javascript, is there a way to do that in the above example shown? I really don't like to use this in javascript but I don't find a way to do that.

Comment: A but late, but I believe in that example you could substitute the name of the object, `obj`, for `this` when calling `.doSomethingElse`.

Comment: The link to your benchmark is dead for me, but I can't see how you could get significant results when your timer is 4 or 5 orders of magnitude slower than the duration you aim to measure.

Answer (score 0):

jsperf is dead. meet [perf.link](https://perf.link/#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%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%3D%3D).

i'm seeing a different victor each time i run the benchmark. my guess is, modern browsers optimize away most of the disadvantages of either of these approaches.