# Anyway to avoid creating a JavaScript function each time? (alternative to closure)

Tags: javascript, closures

Suppose I have the following jQuery code:

```
var FooBar = {
    zizzle: function (callback) {
        var x, y, z;
        // … do stuff with x y and z
        callback(z, y, z);
    }
}

$("a[href]").each(function () {
    var link = this;

    // do things with the link, e.g. 
    $(link).data('fiddle', "deedee")

    function do_something() {
        console.log("I would use the link variable here:", link)
        // lots of code here using link
        // blah, blah, blah link
    }

    $(this).click(function () {
        FooBar.zizzle(do_something);
    });
});
```

Currently, because `do_something` is inside of the function where `link` is defined it has access to that variable (closure). However, I'm wondering whether it's possible to avoid creating the function for every link. I'd rather do something closer to this:

```
var FooBar = {
    zizzle: function (callback) {
        var x, y, z;
        // … do stuff with x y and z
        callback(z, y, z);
    }
}

function do_something() {
    console.log("I would use the link variable here:", link)
    // lots of code here using link
    // blah, blah, blah link
}

$("a[href]").each(function () {
    var link = this;

    // do things with the link, e.g. 
    $(link).data('fiddle', "deedee")

    $(this).click(function () {
        FooBar.zizzle(do_something);
    });
});
```

So that `do_something` is only created once. However, if I do this, then `do_something` no longer has a value for `link`.

Assume in this case that it's not possible to change the code for `FooBar` and that it expects just a callback and can't send along any additional parameters.

The only alternative I've thought of is something like this, which at least only creates functions as needed:

```
var FooBar = {
    zizzle: function (callback) {
        var x, y, z;
        // … do stuff with x y and z
        callback(z, y, z);
    }
}

function do_something_maker(link) {
    return function (x, y, z) {
        console.log("I would use the link variable here:", link)
        // lots of code here using link
        // blah, blah, blah link
    }
}

$("a[href]").each(function () {
    var link = this;

    // do things with the link, e.g. 
    $(link).data('fiddle', "deedee")

    $(this).click(function () {
        FooBar.zizzle(do_something_maker(link));
    });
});
```

Is that the best option?

Comment: I think that's a fine approach, but aren't you still creating a new function per click? By the way, such questions would be a better fit in [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: But your last option creates a new function each time the click event is triggered, doesn't it?

Comment: `$.proxy()`, look into it.

Comment: $("body").on("click", "a[href]",  function(e){
  do_something_maker.call(this, this);
});

Comment: You don't seem to ever `var link;`

Comment: @PaulS. you're right, fixed.

Comment: @dandavis I also need to do other things with the `link` object; adjusted code to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
var FooBar = {
    zizzle: function (callback) {
        var x, y, z;
        // … do stuff with x y and z
        callback(z, y, z);
    }
}

function do_something() {
    console.log("I would use the link variable here:", do_something.link);
    //if no link exists, abort
    if(!do_something.link){return;}
    //code with do_something.link


    //you might want to delete afterwards
    //delete do_something.link;
}

$("a[href]").click(function () {
    do_something.link = this;
    FooBar.zizzle(do_something);
});
```

In case you have something async and slow ongoing, you can try to make it lazy like do_something_maker or the bind/$.proxy approach, but only once for each link (on the first click and add it to $.data).

```
var FooBar = {
    zizzle: function (callback) {
        var x, y, z;
        // … do stuff with x y and z
        callback(z, y, z);
    }
}

function do_something() {
    console.log("I would use the link variable here:", this);

}

$("a[href]").click(function () {
    var fn = $.data(this, 'zizzleCB') || $.data(this, 'zizzleCB', do_something.bind(this));
    FooBar.zizzle(fn);
});
```

Comment: The only problem with this is if the callbacks are called more than once and not used in the same order of the event.  That last assignment of `do_something.link` will always be used.

Comment: That would work, but could cause problems if there's something async happening.

Comment: @Smeegs only if async behaviour is there.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas That's the scenario I was describing.

Comment: bind is the same as create_do_something, you'll create a function for each anchor.

Comment: @HMR you don't get the point here. create_do_something is creating a new function on each click for each control. my example is using bind only on first click and stores the created function in $.data (so it is lazy and it is doing it only once for a clicked control). your example above is also creating a new closure/function on each click. But he wants to reduce them!

Comment: You're correct. you didn't pass the closure to `$(this).click` I stand corrected. Would it not be simpler to use event and pass `e.target to do_something`?  like so: `Foobar.zizzle=function(fn,el){
  console.log(el.href);fn(el);
};
$("a[href]").click(function (e) {
    FooBar.zizzle(fn,e.target);
});`

Comment: You can solve the async problem mentioned for the first solution by using an array of links

 `function do_something() {
     var link = do_something.links.shift();
            ...
 }

 do_something.links = [];

 $("a[href]").click(function () {
     do_something.links.push(this);
            ...
 });`

Comment: I've updated my answer, even though you don't add a closure for every found anchor jQuery does it for you if you use `$(selector).click` or `$(selector).on("click"` That means that as a programmer you may have ease of mind that you didn't add a closure but jQuery does it for you. The general way of handling lots of elements is adding one listener to the container and have that handler figure out what action to take on what event.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just passing "link" as an argument to your zizzle function and pass it to the callback ?

sth like :

```
var FooBar = {
    zizzle: function (callback,link) {
        var x, y, z;
        // … do stuff with x y and z
        callback(x, y, z, link);
    }
}

function do_something(x, y, z, link) {
    console.log("I would use the link variable here:", link)
    // lots of code here using link
    // blah, blah, blah link
}

$("a[href]").on("click", function () {
    FooBar.zizzle(do_something, this);
});
```

Comment: The question states that the code for `Foobar` can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the kicks:

```
var Util = function() {};
Util.prototype.do_something = function() {};

var FooBar = function() {
};
FooBar.prototype.zizzle = function(fn) {};

var fooBar = new FooBar();
var util = new Util();
fooBar.zizzle(util.do_something);
```

What has this given you?

Well for each `FooBar` object you create you will have 1 less instance of `zizzle` (since all functions are objects you effectively have 1 less).
For each instance of `Util`, you will have 1 less instance of `do_something`
AND you can now decide better when you want a `Util` instance and not clutter the global object with an unused function.

This works because we're defining one function on the prototype instead of letting the functions run rampant in a object literal `{}` or attach them to the global namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can use Function.prototype.bind:

```
var FooBar = {
    zizzle: function (callback) {
        var x, y, z;
        // … do stuff with x y and z
        callback(z, y, z);
    }
}

function do_something() {
    console.log("'this' refers to link here", this)
    // lots of code here using link
    // blah, blah, blah link
}

$("a[href]").each(function () {
    link = this;
    $(this).click(function () {
        FooBar.zizzle(do_something.bind(link));
    });
});
```

Comment: which is mostly the same as do_something_maker.

Comment: I understand that .bind creates a new function; does anyone know if it does it more efficiently than how do_something_maker works?

Comment: [I guess bind is slower than a closure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17638540/1348391)

Answer (score 0):

You should register click on the container of the elements you're interested in. In your case that would be document.body. Then have an extra selector figure out when to take action: http://api.jquery.com/on/ Here is an example

```
function create_do_something($link){
  return function(z,y,x){
    do_something(z,y,x);
  };
}
$(document.body).on("click","a[href]",function () {
  var $link =  this;
  FooBar.zizzle(create_do_something($link));
});
```

Just found out something, if you have any solution using `$("a[href]").click` or `$("a[href]").on` jQuery will create a closure for every found element in the selector.

Running some tests in Chrome and doing a heap snapshot has the following result:

**No jQuery and no JS code:**

2557 closures

**No code at all (just jQuery and jQuery ui):**

5832 closures

**With the following code**

```
$(document.body).on("click","div"
  ,function(){console.log("hi");});
```

5834 closures(with 2 divs)

5834 closures(with 100 divs), notice that the amount of closures stays the same

**With the following code**

```
$("div").click(function(){console.log("hi");});
```

5835 closures(with 2 divs)

5933 closures(with 100 divs), notice there are 98 closures more so jQuery adds a closure for you on every found element in the selector.

So why does `$("div").click` have more closures?

jQuery 1.10.2 unminified on line 4762:

```
 eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {
```

When you set a break point there you'll see jQuery add a closure for each element found in the selector. So $("div") returned a hundred where $(document.body) has one no matter how many divs.

Comment: Sorry, the code was an oversimplification; I'll change it to make it a little bit clearer. And as I said, I can't make any changes to FooBar, so it can't take the event object.

Comment: @JordanReiter Missed the fact you can't change FooBar, you can still add the event listener to the container (all anchors would be the document) or not use the `.each` and add the event listener on `$("a[href]")`

Comment: @JordanReiter I've updated my answer, please let me know if you need any help.