# ES6 classes private member syntax

Tags: javascript, class, private, ecmascript-6

I have a quick question. What's the cleanest and straightforward way to declare private members inside ES6 classes?

In other words, how to implement

```
function MyClass () {
  var privateFunction = function () {
    return 0;
  };

  this.publicFunction = function () {
    return 1;
  };
}
```

as

```
class MyClass {

  // ???

  publicFunction () {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849064/how-to-implement-private-method-in-es6-class-with-traceur

Comment: Thanks, Dan, that pretty much answers my question

Answer (score 4):

It's not much different for classes. The body of the constructor function simply becomes the body of `constructor`:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    var privateFunction = function () {
      return 0;
    };

    this.publicFunction = function () {
      return 1;
    };
  }
}
```

Of course `publicFunction` could also be a real method like in your example, if it doesn't need access to `privateFunction`.

I'm not particularily advising to do this (I'm against pseudo privat properties for various reasons), but that would be the most straightforward translation of your code.

Comment: In theory, true privacy will be in ES7.

Comment: True privacy via syntax perhaps., but you can already get true privacy via WeakMaps.

Comment: This way, you're defining a `publicFunction` in every instance of your `MyClass` members, instead of defining it once on `MyClass.prototype`

Comment: @Masious: yes, that’s necessary if `publicFunction` needs to access `privateFunction`. That’s why I said if it doesn’t need to access `privateFunction` it could be a “real method”. But I could have expressed that clearer.