# Closure or Bind

Tags: javascript, binding, closures

Is there any difference between limiter 1 and limiter 2?

```
var limiter1 = function(limiter){
   return function(item){
      return item > limiter;
   };    
};
var limiter2 = function(limiter){
   return function(limiter,item){
      return item > limiter;
   }.bind(this,limiter);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, they will function identically. However...

If you ever start to actually use the value of `this`, the function returned by `limiter1` will be unbound (so a consumer could change the value with a call to `Function.prototype.bind`).  In `limiter2`, it's locked down with the initial `bind` call.

Also, they use different levels of scope to get the `limiter` variable.  Depending on the engine, you could have a (minute) difference in performance.

Comment: And witch one would be the faster in that case?

Comment: There is no single case, and it's so small that you would be wasting your time optimizing in 99.9% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

The .bind algorithm is a lot more complicated than wrapping a function with another function. However, most of the time it does not matter. I think that using native .bind usually provides for more readable and maintainable code - which is a big plus.

You can see more about this [Why is bind slower than a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638305/why-is-bind-slower-than-a-closure)

Comment: I think if I already have the wrapped function(so it's not an anonymous), than I must use the bind method, but if I create the function on the fly than the bind method become unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.