# jQuery Multiple Callbacks "this" reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm working on adding a few functionality changes to a jQuery component through event callback functions input through a configuration object.

I'd really like to separate each functionality change into it's own set of functions.

What I am wondering is how best to handle the "this" reference. Since there will be multiple functions I want to attach to each callback, I'm assuming I'll need an anonymous function for each option that calls the others. Would I simply pass "this" reference through as a parameter to my functions, or is there a better way to do this?

```
function somePluginAfterSelectFeatureOne(this, param ){
  // do stuff
}

function somePluginAfterSelectFeatureTwo(this, param){
  // do stuff
}

$('.some-element').somePlugin({
  afterSelect: function(param){
     somePluginAfterSelectFeatureOne(this, param);
  }
});
```

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) is worth a read.  Try to get all the answers in the quiz right - when you can do so, have another think about your design and the best way to do it :)  Also further reading about managing `this` within callbacks in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).

Comment: btw you can't use `this` as a parameter name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes i would recommend "apply" or closures - i'm not sure what about performance.. i barely remember there was a reason why closuers work better than binding "this", but i don't believe there is a real big deal which one you want. And closures just doesn't always makes sense because it's pretty tight bound to the architecture/design of your app.

Well first of all - i would never pass "this" just as a parameter of your function, javascript knows much better ways to achieve this:

```
function somePluginAfterSelectFeatureOne(param ){
  // do stuff
}

function somePluginAfterSelectFeatureTwo(param){
  // do stuff
}

$('.some-element').somePlugin({
  afterSelect: function(param){
     somePluginAfterSelectFeatureOne(param);
  }
});
```

First, remove "this" as param from your function params, it's just wrong ;)

And now the call "somePluginAfterSelectFeatureOne(param)" will fail because, what would be *this*? Well "this" will lead to the scope which was valid when you defined your function (hard to explain, try to debug that down ;))

Anyways - to control the "this" of your function, you simply rewrite the call:

```
somePluginAfterSelectFeatureOne.apply(this, [param]);
```

Now, i guess the "this" which is already available inside of your "afterSelect: function(param){ }" call would be the correct one, right? So, by using the native function "apply", you're able to pass a new "this" to the called function and, still you're able to pass all normal params -> this is just the second param of "apply". But be aware, when using apply -> all params must be passed as an Array (since the internal "arguments" param which is *always* available on every function call, is in fact an array internally)

Now, this is still the solution with direct bind's - closures are still a different game:

```
$('.some-element').somePlugin({
  afterSelect: function(param){
     var _self = this,
         myFunction = function(param) {
             _self.anotherFn(param)
         };

     myFunction(param);         
  }
});
```

As you can see - we simply store "this" as a local variable called "_self".. Now, if the function definition is in the same scope like above -> "_self" will be available on it, even without passing it (that's what we call a "closure" ;)).

But as you can also see - it doesn't always make sense... in your example, you would be forced to move the function definitions inside of your "afterSelect" function, which is totally not the goal here.

So, i would go with an "apply" pattern and passing the "this" nicely - kind of a "delegate" ;)

Oh and to make a complete roundup - it's also possible to override "this" directly on function definition level. Use "bind" for this:

```
function myFunction(param) {
    this.secondFunction(param)
}.bind(somethingDifferentWhichWillBeUsedAsThisInside)
```

I got also some all-time favorited threads regarding these two topics here:

- [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)
- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work?lq=1)
- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: It usually doesn't matter but [bind is slower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638305/why-is-bind-slower-than-a-closure)

Comment: Thanks for clarify that Brian ;)

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not a valid parameter name. Change it to `element` and pass it to your custom functions.

I prefer not to use `this` unless it's within a prototype method (or the constructor).

```
function somePluginAfterSelectFeatureOne(element, param ){
  // `element` is what you wanted `this` to be 
}

$('.some-element').somePlugin({
  afterSelect: function(param){
     somePluginAfterSelectFeatureOne(this, param);
  }
});
```

If you really want to use `this`, you could use `Function.prototype.call`

```
function somePluginAfterSelectFeatureOne(param ){
    console.log(this); // The element that the event fired on 
}

$('.some-element').somePlugin({
  afterSelect: function(param){
     somePluginAfterSelectFeatureOne.call(this, param);
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice! Hitting the nail to the head with about 2000 fewer words than i did :P

Comment: @jebbie :) I also wanted to point out that using `this` from global (or any free standing) functions looks really weird and confusing.