# Typescript reference right this in callback

Tags: angular, typescript, this, ionic2

When I try to use the `sendUserMessage()` from Class 1 I get an error that `content` is undefined. I know that it has to do with the `this` but I am unable to find an answer that fits into my situation.

Class 1:

```
    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

    sendUserMessage(message) {
        this.class2object.sendMessageToBackend(message,this.createMessage);

    }


    createMessage(jsonMessage) {
        this.content.scrollToBottom(300);
    }
```

Class 2:

```
 sendMessageToBackend(ChatMessage: string, handler: Function) {
    //build requests
    var response: string;
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    var json = JSON.stringify({ message: ChatMessage, sessionID: "", timestamp: time });
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');

    // send request
    this.http.post('http:somethhing.smth',
        json, {
            headers: headers
        }).subscribe(data => {
            response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.text()));
            handler(response);
        },
        () => console.log("error")
        );
}
```

Note: Methods here are simplified for better understanding.

I get the error `EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`

I know that one solution would be to move the method in Class 2 to Class 1 but I would really try to avoid this.

Comment: use `console.log(this.content)` inside `createMessage` and check whether it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an arrow function:

```
this.class2object.sendMessageToBackend(message, jsonMessage => this.createMessage(jsonMessage));
```

I suggest to read this article: [Understanding "This" in JavaScript](https://www.codementor.io/javascript/tutorial/understanding--this--in-javascript).

*Notice: The closure (our small arrow function) [has better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638305/why-is-bind-slower-than-a-closure#answer-17638540) than the `bind` function.*

Answer (score 0):

Use bind function

```
 this.class2object.sendMessageToBackend(message, this.createMessage.bind(this));
```

Hope it help.