# JSX binding this to a function within a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am using a map function and have tested and confirmed that within the maps function this is referencing the class object as desired.

When I try passing this again by binding it to a jsx function, it doesn't pass this as desired.

Error: Uncaught TypeError: _this3.checkType(...).bind is not a function

```
// wrapped in a class

checkType(type, options, placeholder, name, handleUpdatedValue, defvalue, index) {

        console.log(this);

        switch(type) {
            case 'select':
                return <select onChange={handleUpdatedValue.bind(this)} >{options.map((option, i) => <option value={option} key={i}>{option}</option>)}</select>
                break;
            case 'text':
                return <input onChange={handleUpdatedValue.bind(this)} name={name} placeholder={placeholder} type="text" />
                break;
            case 'date':
                return <input onChange={handleUpdatedValue.bind(this)} name={name} placeholder={placeholder} type="date" />
                break;
            default: 
                console.log('Error: Invalid Type');
        }
        return type === 'select' ? <select></select> : <input />
    }

return(
        <div className="formwrapper thinshadow">    
            <h3>{this.props.header}</h3>
            {this.getFields().map((field, i) => {
                <div key={i} className={field.classes}>
                    {this.checkType(field.type, field.options, field.placeholder, field.name, this.handleUpdatedValue.bind(this), field.defvalue, field.index).bind(this)}

                                                                  // DOES NOT WORK ^

                    <div className="minilabel"></div>
                </div>
            }, this)}                                         // THIS WORKS

            <button className="btn btn-primary" 
                    onClick={() => this.props.onClick(values)} >
                    Save
            </button>
        </div>  
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking the function instead of binding it.

```
this.checkType(field.type, field.options, field.placeholder, field.name, this.handleUpdatedValue.bind(this), field.defvalue, field.index).bind(this)
```

should be

```
this.checkType.bind(this, field.type, field.options, field.placeholder, field.name, this.handleUpdatedValue.bind(this), field.defvalue, field.index)
```

**`bind` Usage**

```
fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]]
```

Refer to this link for more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

**Edit**

You use `bind` when you are passing your function to another context (another `this` pretty much), and still want the function to be invoked under the original `this`.

In your situation, you don't need to bind because within your `map`, you have the same `this`. See [You Don't Need to Bind This in React when using forEach and map](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2876-you-don-t-need-to-use-bind-this-when-using-foreach-or-map-in-reactjs.htm).

But if you do want to, I strongly advise against `bind`ing when you are iterating. You can use closure, and `bind` before the iteration.

[`bind` is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638305/why-is-bind-slower-than-a-closure), even though it doesn't really matter most of the time. But more importantly, you don't want to `bind` in iterations like `forEach` or `map` because it's easy to lose the context (`this`) without knowing (when you are not using React). And you will scratch you head for a few hours.

If you are using React, you can `bind` in the `render` function.

```
render: () {
  const checkType = this.checkType.bind(this);
  render (
    map((node) => { checkType(...) });
  );
}
```

Comment: I am trying to invoke it while maintaining this. The functions purpose is to return the correct field. If I do the .bind, it removes the error, but does not invoke the function. I am new at this so please excuse me if I don't understand your solution. Nevermind, just saw your link, thank you!

Comment: @Sequential You can simply call `this.checkType(...)`. I will add an edit for more details.