# React performance: bind vs anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know if there is a performance difference between using `bind` and an anonymous function in React components.

Concretely, is one of the following more performant than another?

```
const MyComponent = ({ myHandler }) => {
  ...
  return (
    <a onClick={myHandler.bind(this, foo, bar)} ...>
      hello world
    </a>
  );
}

const MyComponent = ({ myHandler }) => {
  ...
  return (
    <a
      onClick={() => {
        myHandler(this, foo, bar)
      }
      ...
    >
      hello world
    </a>
  );
}
```

This question is different from the possible duplicate because the answer to the possible duplicate question focuses on the memory footprint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda functions vs bind, memory! (and performance)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117911/lambda-functions-vs-bind-memory-and-performance)

Comment: Neither: if you need to create an anonymous function to handle an event it's a strong signal that part of the current component need to be extracted to a new component. With all of the handler parameters to be the new component props.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, the way you are setting your question is a bit erraneous:

Your first example `<a onClick={myHandler.bind(this, foo, bar)} ...>` creates a new function on each render that is bound to the context of the component and always has `foo` and `bar` as the first two arguments.

Your second example `<a onClick={() => myHandler(this, foo, bar)} ...>` instead calls `myHandler` with 3 arguments, `this`, `foo` and `bar`, where this represents the component context.

On the theoretical level you're discussing about two concepts: is binding `this` to the function more expensive than creating a new anonymous bound function and calling the function there? I would say that both approaches are very similar from the performance point of view: you're creating a new function ([func.bind docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) in both cases.

Any performance differences would be so small that you likely will never develop such a performance-critical piece of software where choosing between `() => {}` and `bind` would be an issue.

If you wish to enhance performance here, opt to use a `class` and bind the click handler to the context in the `constructor`. That way you do not need to create a new function every time you render.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

If there is a difference, the difference will be so small that I would be very surprised if you were able to contrive a test where it's even measurable, let alone ever noticeable. Go with the version that's easier for you and other people in the same code base to understand.