# Angular 5: Service Getter Why Double Arrow if Referenced to Getter instead of Calling Getter Directly

Tags: angular

I have a service which is loading basic system information which I want to share between several components.

If I make a getter method `this` in the getter becomes the component's `this` if I not use double arrows in the service.

## service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WhoAmIService {

  constructor() { }
  whoAmI = 'I\'m a service'
  getterOne(): string {
    return this.whoAmI
  }
  getterTwo = (): string => {
    return this.whoAmI
  }  

}
```

## component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WhoAmIService } from './who-am-i.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  whoAmI = 'I\'m a component'
  getterOne: Function
  getterTwo: Function
  constructor(
    private whoAmIService: WhoAmIService
  ) {
    this.getterOne = whoAmIService.getterOne
    this.getterTwo = whoAmIService.getterTwo
    console.log('cool', whoAmIService.getterOne())
    console.log('cool', whoAmIService.getterTwo())
    console.log('why is this different', this.getterOne())
    console.log('cool', this.getterTwo())    
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxsven

## Question

Why do I need the arrow function if I assign the getter function to the component?

Comment: I can't explain this to you in technical terms but if you follow this link and see how typescript gets trans-piled, you will understand it. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20WhoAmIService%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20whoAmI%20%3D%20'I%5C'm%20a%20service'%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getterOne()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.whoAmI%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getterTwo%20%3D%20()%3A%20string%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.whoAmI%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever function is assigned to any other variable, actually copies the function definition and act as new function which has the same codes.

You can think as it is clone of the original function.

Now important point is the `context` where this function is getting executed. So `this` is nothing but the `context` where is it being executed.

**Now lets come back to your example**

1. `whoAmIService.getterOne()` - this getting executed on inside the `whoAmIService`so the `context` (`this`) point to `whoAmIService`.
2. `this.getterOne()` - Here this will point to `AppComponent` class since the context is `AppComponent`.

Note : This is nothing to do with Angular. Its Javascript concept.

Just visit this for more info - https://hackernoon.com/execution-context-in-javascript-319dd72e8e2c

Comment: Thx, That is the important point: `actually copies the function definition`

Answer (score 1):

For normal function syntax, the scope of `this` generally changes resulting in unexpected behavior. That's what's happening in your case.

The newer Arrow Function syntax fixes this issue by retaining the scope of `this`. That's why you can simply rely on it to make it work and show the expected behavior.

If you still want to make it work using the old `function` syntax, you'll have to `bind` the service instance as shown below:

```
console.log('why is this different', this.getterOne.bind(this.whoAmIService)());
```

Here are a few articles and SO OPs for your ref:

1. [Lambda functions vs bind, memory! (and performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117911/lambda-functions-vs-bind-memory-and-performance)
2. [Arrow Functions: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description)

Here's your [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-this-lambda-bind-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for any ref.

Comment: Ok so `=>` s always superior to bind, then I will use always the arrow fn if I reference to this inside the function.