# binding an instance method vs wrapping in an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

[This is related to [Bound function instead of closure to inject extra arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25778841/558639), but that was neither clearly asked nor answered.]

I'm calling a function that expects a function as its argument.  I want to pass a method from my class, bound to an instance of my class.  To make it clear, assume my class looks like:

```
var MyClass = function() {}
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() { ... }

var my_instance = new MyClass();
```

Is there any substantive difference between using `bind`:

```
doSomething(my_instance.myMethod.bind(my_instance))
```

and wrapping the call in an anonymous function:

```
doSomething(function() { my_instance.myMethod(); })
```

?

Comment: The effective difference is *when* `my_instance` (and `my_instance.myMethod`) is resolved. Assuming that none of the bindings change they will both have `this` of "my_instance" when the method is invoked. There will be slight differences with the call frames, but *shrug*.

Comment: I'm not really sure what 'better' means here, since `bind` is considered.

Comment: @user2864740 I removed the "is there something better" question since it muddies the primary intent of this post.

Comment: @user2864740 Post your first comment as a response and I'll give it a checkmark.  I hadn't considered the time at which the args are bound.

Answer (score 2):

If a prototype within your class needs to generate a callback, it may not know its instance's name.  As a result, you'll need to use `this`, but the value of `this` depends on where the callback was executed.

Consider the following example:

```
var MyClass = function (x) { this.something = x; };
MyClass.prototype.makeCall = function () {
    var myBadCallback  = function() { console.log(this.something); };
    var myGoodCallback = function() { console.log(this.something); }.bind(this);

    // When called, the value of "this" points to... we don't know
    callMeBack( myBadCallback );

    // When called, the value of "this" points to this instance
    callMeBack( myGoodCallback );
};


function callMeBack( callback ) { callback(); };

var foo = new MyClass('Hello World!');
var bar = new MyClass('Goodbye!');

// Probably prints "undefined", then prints "Hello World!"
foo.makeCall();

// Probably prints "undefined", then prints "Goodbye!"
bar.makeCall();
```

In the above example, the first output probably prints `undefined` because the context (what `this` refers to) has changed by the time the callback has executed.

This example may seem contrived, but these sort of situations *do* arise, a common case being AJAX callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

in "Mr. Llama" example if we use arrow function then the problem is solved and we don't need the bind() .i.e. This:

```
 var myBadCallback = () => { console.log(this.something); };
```

Instead of:

```
  var myBadCallback  = function() { console.log(this.something); };
```

Because in arrow function the "this" keyword refers to the object where the function is defined and not where it is used. so "this" is always predictable. Here is the updated version

```js
const MyClass = function (x) { this.something = x; };
MyClass.prototype.makeCall = function () {
    const myBadCallback  = () => { console.log(this.something); };
    const myGoodCallback = function() { console.log(this.something); }.bind(this);

    // When called, the value of "this" points to... we don't know
    callMeBack( myBadCallback );

    // When called, the value of "this" points to this instance
    callMeBack( myGoodCallback );
};


function callMeBack( callback ) { callback(); };

const foo = new MyClass('Hello World!');
const bar = new MyClass('Goodbye!');

// both print "Hello World!"
foo.makeCall();

// both print "Goodbye!"
bar.makeCall();
```