# Advantages to using bind versus using a local reference to this?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Are there advantages or differences to using `_.bind` versus using a local reference to `this`?

Here's a very simplified example: `doAdd` is an example of a local function that needs to effect a property on the parent object; it's ultimately run as a callback function inside `doSomethingThenCallback`. Option A vs. option B:

```
var obj = {
    num: 1,

    // Option A
    add_A: function() {
        function doAdd(){
            this.num++;
        }
        // Make the "this" in the function refer to the parent object
        doAdd = _.bind(doAdd, this);
        doSomethingThenCallback(doAdd);
    },

    // Option B
    add_B: function() {
        // Save a local reference to "this"
        var o = this;
        function doAdd(){
            o.num++;
        }
        doSomethingThenCallback(doAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need lexical this than bind it. it is better practice, it's cleaner and less prone to errors. if you need reference to both 'this' then assign it to variable.

Comment: @webduvet Can you elaborate as an answer? Would be good to see what kind of errors it helps prevent.

Comment: Your `_.bind(doAdd, this)` does nothing useful, `_.bind` returns the bound function, it doesn't modify it in-place.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397096/function-bind-vs-closure-in-javascript-how-to-choose.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks. I made an edit to correct that.

Comment: You left out an option that seems to be fairly common these days: you can provide a second context argument to `doSomethingThenCallback` so that it can call the callback with whatever `this` you need using [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). The choice is mostly a matter of personal taste, cases where it matters are fairly rare.